# Java code for date functions

Tags: java

Can any one help me with the code for adding some number of days to any date..?

For example  today is 11-04-2014.   I want 15-04-2014 + 3 days  output:18-04-2014.

My question is not adding dates to current date..

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for the Calendar class.

Comment: `DateTime.now().plusDays(3)` // with joda-time

Comment: Both the old `Date`/`Calendar` classes and the Joda-Time project are now supplanted by the java.time classes bundled with Java 8 and later.  `LocalDate().plusDays( 5 )`

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you can write:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2014, 4, 11);
LocalDate newDate = date.plusDays(3);
System.out.println(newDate); //  Prints 2014-04-14
```

Its that simple.

Comment: This is the best Answer, using the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes `Calendar` & `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String dateString = "11-04-2014" // Say you have a date in String format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); // Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat with the right format.
Date date = format.parse(dateString); // Then parse the string, this will need a try catch statement.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Get an instance of the calendar.
calendar.setTime(date); // Set the time of the calendar to the parsed date
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 3); // Add the days to the calendar
String outputFormat = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);

        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calendar function:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateInstance);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, NO_OF_DAYS_TO_ADD);
Date addedDays = cal.getTime();
```

DateInstance is the date you are using. addedDays can be formatted using SimpleDateFormat to display in any date format that you would like to use.